# Name for "adjoint map" on $C^\ast$ algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose we have a $C^\ast$ algebra $A$ and a linear map $\phi\colon A\to A$, and assume that $\phi$ does not satisfy $\phi(x)^\ast\ne \phi(x^\ast)$ for some $x$, i.e. is **not** a $\ast$-homomorphism.

**Question:** Is there a name for the map
$$\overline\phi\colon A\to A, \quad \overline{\phi}(x):=\phi(x^\ast)^\ast$$
which is linear and has the properties $\phi(x)^\ast=\overline\phi(x^\ast)$ and $\overline{\overline{\phi}}=\phi$?

Comment: I would be surprised if it has a name.  Whenever I've seen this, it's only given a notation.

Comment: @Aweygan Thanks! What would be typical notations you have encountered?

Comment: Either $\overline\phi$ or $\phi^*$.